# Add New Key/Value to Dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a `dictionary` of type `[String: [String]]` and is loaded as blank `[ : ]`.

Is there a way I can append a value to the array associated to a new string key? (i.e. `exampleDict["test"].append("test")`)

When I print out the dictionary after attempting this, I am returned `[ : ]`, which I believe is because the key does not exist and returns as nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift has a neat "default" feature for doing things exactly like this.

```
exampleDict["test", default: []].append("test")
```

If `exampleDict["test"]` is nil, the `default` is returned instead. If you modify the returned default object, that modification goes into the dictionary.

Unfortunately this only works properly for value types, since classes aren't reassigned when they're mutated. Fortunately, `Array` is a value type, so this will work perfectly here.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [`Dictionary.subscript(_:default:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894528-subscript).

```
exampleDict["test", default: []].append("test")
```